# ASP.NET MVC 2 Returning to previous screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to return to the previous view without having to record all the parameters that were used to get to the view in question. Consider this situation. You have a search screen with input parameters, you press search and get results displayed on the page. You click on one item to get a detailed look which redirects you to a new view. Does MVC have the ability to get the previous query string that contains the search parameters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Request.UrlReferrer

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. You could save it in the session, but how about using JS history.back()

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the user just use the back button on the browser?  Are you wanting to present a "Back to results" link on the detail page?  Also look at Request.UrlReferrer if you don't want to save the search parameters in session or a cookie.

Comment: I dont want any unexpected behaviour to arise from pressing the backbutton. Im not familiar enough with mvc to know exactly what would happen, and i want to make sure that my users dont eff up the database somehow.